# Unable to associate models without manually assigning the foreign key in Laravel 5

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm running into an issue when trying to associate a child model to a parent in Laravel 5.

I see in the documentation under the [Inserting Related Models](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#inserting-related-models)'s "Associating Models (Belongs To)" section that I should be able to:

- Create a child model instance: `$comment = new Comment(['message' => 'A new comment.']);`
- Get the parent record: `$post = Post::find(1);`
- Use the parent record's association method to save the child which should automatically relate it to the parent: `$comment = $post->comments()->save($comment);`

This makes sense to me conceptually, the problem I'm having is creating the child record without manually assigning the parent's id as a foreign key.

In my project, I have have a parent table `Accounts` and a child table `Events`. The Events schema has a foreign key constraint assigned for the Accounts id:

```
Schema::create('events', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('account_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('account_id')->references('id')->on('accounts');
    $table->timestamp('date_of_donation');
    $table->timestamp('date_last_donation_letter_sent');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

So when I go to create the Events instance that I'm planning on associating to the parent Accounts I get an exception thrown:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'account_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `events` (`date_of_donation`, `date_last_donation_letter_sent`, `account_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2015-05-16, , , 2015-05-16 17:35:36, 2015-05-16 17:35:36))

I understand why the error is thrown because I'm not giving the Events instance a foreign key value.

I can get around it by getting the Accounts record first and creating the Events instance like so:

```
$account = $accounts->findOrFail($id);
$event = $events->create(['account_id' => $account->id, ...]);
```

But it seems like the whole point of the "Associating Models (Belongs To)" section is so that you *don't* have to do this.

Am I missing or misunderstanding something about how the associating functionality is supposed to work?

## Update

Here's my `Account` model:

```
<?php namespace Hub;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Account extends Model {

    protected $fillable =[
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'display_name',
        'email',
        'zipcode',
        'phone_number'
    ];

    public function donationEvents(){
        return $this->hasMany('Hub\donationEvent');
    }


}
```

And my `Event` model:

```
<?php namespace Hub;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Event extends Model {

    protected $fillable = [
        'account_id',
        'date_of_donation',
        'date_last_donation_letter_sent'
    ];

    public function donationItems(){
        return $this->hasMany('Hub\DonationItem');
    }

    public function account(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Hub\Account');
    }
}
```

Also, here's the code that triggers the error:

```
Route::get('dev2', function ( Hub\Account $accounts, Hub\Event $events){
    $account = $accounts->findOrFail(1);

    // This is where I'm trying to create the child record but I get the exception
    $event = $events->create(['date_of_donation' => '2015-05-16', 'date_of_last_donation_letter_sent' => '']);

    $event = $account->events()->save($event);
    return [$account, $event];

});
```

Comment: I think you forgot to put the actual code (that's producing the error) in your question

Comment: post your account model and event model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is, `create()` instantiates a new model and directly saves it. So you actually save it twice. However the first time there is no foreign key set.

Instead of `create()` use `fill()` to set all the values without saving:

```
$event = $events->fill(['date_of_donation' => '2015-05-16', 'date_of_last_donation_letter_sent' => '']);
```

Or you can use the constructor as well (I personally prefer this solution)

```
$event = new Event(['date_of_donation' => '2015-05-16', 'date_of_last_donation_letter_sent' => '']);
```

Comment: AH! Ok, that totally makes sense. Thanks for pointing that out!